# Simple two bulb circuit

Tags: switches

Im trying to draw up a circuit with two bulbs and two spdt switches.
In this circuit one of the two bulbs must always be on, and both switches must be able to swap which bulb is on.

So to avoid any confusion: Both lights must change state (on to off or off to on) when either switch is used, One light must be on the other off, I only have two single pole double throw switches and must use both.

This is seems like a simple circuit like but i am having a very hard time working this out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OMG I knew what the question was going to be before I read the whole thing. It's how lights in the house are wired when you got 2 fliky switches.

Comment: Wait a second, I didn't predict correctly. I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: I think the XOR gate is what you are looking for...

Comment: "Must use both."  Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Smells like a HW assignment. But I believe more components should be involved.

Comment: Is this homework? If not what is the context in which you are trying to do this and what other components are you allowed to use apart from two lamps, two spdt switches and a power source (e.g. battery)?

Comment: its called vavien.

Comment: Start by writing the logic out. Switches have 4 positions 00, 01, 10, 11. Bulbs have 2 positions 01, 10. Assign the switch positions to the desired bulb outcomes, and you should be headed the right way.

Comment: Can you glue a bar to the switches so that operating one operates the other? You did not say that they have to be remote from each other.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: "_Both lights must change state (on to off or off to on) when either switch is used._" \$ either \neq both \$. ;^)

Answer (score 6):

**The simplest (but non-qualifying) solution**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC04BG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. By changing the switch type the problem becomes simple.*

**AC solution**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPO8RG.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. By not changing the switch type the problem is more difficult!*

**Gray code sequence**

A trick to looking at this solution is to write the truth table in [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) rather than a normal binary sequence. This is important because only one switch will be changed at a time and it will be easy to see the lamp status change.

*Table 1. Switch combinations in Gray code sequence.*

```
SW1  SW2  L1   L2
-------------------
 0    0   ON   --
 1    0   --   ON
 1    1   ON   --
 0    1   --   ON
 0    0   ON   --   <-- First step repeated
```

With the Gray code it is easy to see that every one-switch change results in a reversal of the lights' status.

**DC solution**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYPNFB.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. The DC version.*

---

**Binary sequence**

Here is the pattern in binary code sequence.

*Table 2. Switch combinations in binary code sequence.*

```
SW1  SW2  L1   L2
-------------------
 0    0   ON   --
 1    0   --   ON
 0    1   --   ON
 1    1   ON   --
 0    0   ON   --   <-- First step repeated
```

Note how much more difficult it is to visually verify that the requirements have been met.

Comment: He said to only use two SPDT switches, not a SPDT and a DPDT.

Comment: I know but I don't think there's a solution without using more components - either some electronics or a relay to double up the available contacts. I don't think the OP has given us all the constraints. (Nobody else has solved it either.)

Comment: Well my answer got trashed on. And I was within the restrictions. D;

Comment: It's a tough world in here! ;^) OP needs to state AC, DC, wattage, LED/filament, what other components are allowed ...

Comment: Well honestly the OP did not specify how the circuit could be powered, so I assumed it could be in any way. But he did say bulbs which most likely means incandescent bulbs, not LED. Also since he did not specify a power supply, I could get a power supply that has an abnormally high resistance like 1k ohm.

Comment: @Bradman175: See Figure 2.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuUvll.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: But he said "I ONLY have two single pole double throw switches"